# Forbidden word (help) got into question title

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, title

I just tried to edit [this question](//superuser.com/q/1188797/150988): [Excel If statement help](//superuser.com/q/1188797/150988). 
I didn’t try to edit the title. 
When I tried to save my edit, I got an error message box:

> These words are not allowed in titles: 'help'.. See [Writing Good Titles](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/195817#10648).

[image: attempt to edit]

The word “help” [*had been **added*** to the title](//superuser.com/posts/1188797/revisions)
by an edit by somebody else a few minutes before. 
If this word is forbidden, why was that other user able to add it in?

P.S. The user who inserted the blacklisted word
has a little over 1200 rep on Super User, and I have a little over 12,000.

Comment: Well, I thought maybe it was just a client-side check, but it turns out not. It is however an allowed word on this Meta, so my test using this post turned out to be flawed. No idea how it got through.

Comment: Related: [How was a user able to post a question with a title identical to an existing?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/346414/1672723/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks like the check for "help" was a bit naive - this specific instance was entered with some white space after it, which the system allowed.

I have added checks for this issue - and it will no longer be possible to add help followed by any white space.

Comment: Well, I don’t see it when I edit the question and click in the title bar, but I’ll take your word for it. Thanks for your prompt response.

Comment: The system strips out the whitespace if it gets through, @Scott (also strips out repetitions question marks, exclamation points...) So if the check fails to catch it, the system automatically corrects it to a title that *would* have failed the check. Yeah...